# Python flask saml throwing saml2.sigver.SigverError Error Message

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, saml, xmlsec

Has anyone succesfully implemented flask-saml using Windows as dev environment, Python 3.6 and Flask 1.0.2?

I was given the link to the SAML METADATA XML file by our organisation and had it configured on my flask app.

```
app.config.update({
    'SECRET_KEY': 'changethiskeylaterthisisoursecretkey',
    'SAML_METADATA_URL': 'https://<url>/FederationMetadata.xml',
})

flask_saml.FlaskSAML(app)
```

According to the [documentation](https://flask-saml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) this extension will setup the following routes:

- **/saml/logout/:** Log out from the application. This is where users go
  if they click on a “Logout” button.
- **/saml/sso/:** Log in through SAML.
- **/saml/acs/:** After /saml/sso/ has sent you to your IdP it sends you
  back to this path. Also your IdP might provide direct login without
  needing the /saml/sso/ route.

When I go to one of the routes `http://localhost:5000/saml/sso/` I get the error below

> saml2.sigver.SigverError saml2.sigver.SigverError: Cannot find
>   ['xmlsec.exe', 'xmlsec1.exe']

I then went to this site `https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/releases/tag/1.3.5` to get xmlsec and install it. However, I'm still getting the same issue.

Here is a screenshot of how I installed xmlsec

where does not seem to find the xmlsec.exe

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the required executables are in your `PATH`?

Comment: I just started reading through this https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/download.html but not sure if i'm heading in the right direction. Also, I'm not yet sure where the executables should be.

Comment: Anywhere in your PATH, in windows you can check if they are by typing `where xmlsec` in your command prompt

Comment: It does not seem to find xmlsec. I'm now trying to figure out where to get these executables from and how to configure them in my environment.

Comment: Executables found here https://www.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/

Comment: I downloaded the xmlsec1 folder and added the bin folder directory in Environment Variable Path. saml/sso route is working now.

Answer (score 6):

[documentation](https://flask-saml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)is asking to have `xmlsec1` pre-installed. What you installed is a python binding to `xmlsec1`.

Get a windows build of `xmlsec1` from [here](https://www.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/) or build it from [source](https://github.com/lsh123/xmlsec)
And make it available in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

xmlsec won't work properly in windows, better use Linux environment

Type the below `command` before giving `pip install xmlsec`

```
sudo apt-get install xmlsec1
```

Comment: Happy to hear @AjayKumar.